# Mongoid embedded_in many documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, mongoid

I wanna have an Image_Model which defines x, y, width, height, name,...
This model should be embedded_in many other Models.

Example:

```
User embeds_many images
Product embeds_many images
```

is this possible or do I have it like this:

```
User embeds_many user_images
Product embeds_many product_images
```

What is the best way to go?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to do

```
User embeds_many images
Product embeds_many images
```

its better to go with this only as you don't have to remember both the association names when you are querying on image.